# GridBagLayout - adding margin to constraints to move the component to top from center

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am working on my first application to practice layout managers, I started learning the GridBagLayout and I want to create a login window, with a logo and a login box.

Currently my app looks like this:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/a3a74033e71d4c24caa142af0ff3aa63.png))</sub>

I feel that the logo is way too close to the login box, and far away from the top - therefore I need to find a way to give the logo a margin from the bottom, so it goes a bit to the top, so there will be a space between the two components, and the logo will be near the top bar.

Is it possible to do with GridBagLayout?

I've tried setting Insets, to `0, 0, 0, 110` and it moves the logo to the left a bit, not sure why.

```
@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    super.setLayout(layout);
    this.loginPane = new JPanel();
    this.loginPane.setSize(400, 400);
    this.loginPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
    JTextField username = new JTextField();
    username.setSize(200, 45);

    BufferedImage logo = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/logo.png"));
    JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(logo));

    GridBagConstraints t = new GridBagConstraints();
    t.ipadx = logo.getWidth();
    t.ipady = logo.getHeight();
    t.gridx = 0;
    t.gridy = 0;

    super.add(logoLabel, t);
    t.ipadx = 500;
    t.ipady = 300;
    t.gridwidth = 1;
    t.gridheight = 1;
    t.gridy++;
    super.add(loginPane, t);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: A huge Swing developer myself, I'll say this: if you are taking the time to _learn_ a new API, I recommend learning JavaFX instead of Swing. Swing is all but deprecated at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are other properties that you can use for better control on the width and height of the component in percentage.

- [`weightx`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weightx) 
  Specifies how to distribute extra horizontal space.
- [`weighty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weighty) Specifies how to distribute extra vertical space.

It's better expanded under *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Try `t.weighty=0.5;` that will divide both in `50%-50%` and place the component in the center as well. and let me know whether it looks as per your need or not?

---

- Use `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.setSize()` that fits the components as per component's preferred size.
- Override `getPreferredSize()` to set the preferred size of the `JPanel` instead of using `setSize()` method.

sample code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(..., ...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried setting Insets, to 0, 0, 0, 110 and it moves the logo to
>   the left a bit, not sure why.

That's because insets are, in order: top, left, bottom, right

Try `0, 0, 110, 0` instead to offset it from the bottom.